# Caption is not justified using \mathsf

Tags: captions, ieee-style, ieeeaccess

For using the [IEEE Access template](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/) there is problem with subfigures for me (The whole file containing the code can be downloaded from [here](https://gofile.io/d/9QQaAp)). One needs to use

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

However, I noticed when one uses `$\mathsf{M}$` inside caption, the resulting caption is not in justified form. How one can resolve this problem?

The minimal code:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
        T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\let \eucal \mathscr

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}


\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[t!]
    %   \vspace*{-5mm}
    \subfloat[]{
        \includegraphics[scale=0.77]{fig1.png}
    }
    \label{channel1}
    \subfloat[]{
        \includegraphics[scale=0.77]{fig1.png}
    }
    \label{fig1}
    \caption[fig1]{If 
        your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking 
        colleague to carefully proofread your paper. $\mathsf{M}$ spelling.  If 
        your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking 
        colleague to carefully proofread your paper.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}




\EOD
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the site please provide a  full minimal example, then it is a lot easier for others to test your issues.

Comment: @daleif: I just added the minimal code.

Comment: @daleif: I also uploaded the whole file concerning the template.

Comment: The `ieeeaccess` class uses a different model for figures and the `figure` environment doesn't work. There is no provision, as far as I can see, for subfigures.

Comment: @Zarko: As you see after removing `[caption=false]', the caption style (the color and etc) is changed and is not in IEEE Access style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, `ieeeaccess` has no provision for supporting multiple subfloats.

In the code that follows I show how to trick it into making the correct caption. I also show the standard syntax for figures used by the class, to show that the caption is typeset similarly and that `\mathsf` has no role whatsoever in the issue.

Beware of using this, because the people at IEEE might reject your manuscript for not being compliant.

```latex
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\let \eucal \mathscr

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}


\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[Symbol]{upgreek}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for the example


\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\edef\xfigwd{\the\columnwidth}% to trick IEEEaccess

\subfloat[]{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}\label{channel1}%
}\quad
\subfloat[]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image}\label{fig1}%
}

\caption{If your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking 
        colleague to carefully proofread your paper. $\mathsf{M}$ spelling.  If 
        your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking 
        colleague to carefully proofread your paper.}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2][1-3]

\Figure[t!][width=0.9\columnwidth]{example-image}{%
  If your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking
  colleague to carefully proofread your paper. If
  your native language is not English, please get a native English-speaking
  colleague to carefully proofread your paper.\label{another}}

\lipsum[1-12]

\EOD
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I just get confused since in your code the caption is also not justified. Would you please let me know about the standard way in this class that I can add subfigures with no problem?

Comment: @Amin The caption is never justified, which is shown by the second example. That’s how IEEE seems to want the captions are typeset.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.